# Disable HTML5 Audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, audio

I have 4 `<audio>` tags on a page. The client has requested that each snippet of audio be available linearly.

i.e. First available, rest disabled until finished playing, then second becomes available etc.. etc..

Additionally, they've requested that the audio bars remain visible on screen (I was just going to add them dynamically) just not 'active'.

So the question is: How do I disable an audio tag when the `disabled` attribute ( `<audio disabled>` ) doesn't exist..

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
Even a CSS, JS or JQuery answer would be appreciated... All I want to do is mimic a disabled button but for html audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the html to be something like:

```
<audio src='...' controls id='audio1'></audio>
<audio src='...' controls id='audio2'></audio>
<audio src='...' controls id='audio3'></audio>
<audio src='...' controls id='audio4'></audio>
```

then my JQuery solution would be:

```
var audios = ['audio1', 'audio2', 'audio3', 'audio4'];
var canPlay = 0;


$('audio').each(function(){

    this.addEventListener('play', function(){
        if(this.id!=audios[canPlay]){
            this.pause();
            this.currentTime = 0;
        }
    });

    this.addEventListener('ended', function(){
        canPlay = (canPlay + 1) % audios.length;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also disable an audio tag if you add `style="pointer-events:none"` to it…

Comment: Along with this, decreasing the opacity of the audio tag would help in mimicking the look of a disabled element